# Monitoring a Third-party Software's SQL Server Instance - Grafana

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, grafana, metrics

We run a third party software in our company, it uses SQL Server. We recently moved this software to cloud solution bla bla bla and users are now complaining about the slowness when using it. ( we could blame the cloud, but we have other stuff there .. plus this software always had some slowness issues)

I use Grafana for my java APIs and thought of using it to monitor this SQL Server instance.

I believe this is more a SQL Server question...

We have full reading access to database... so can I monitor execution time of running queries?

Like.. when somebody do something in the software, it does execute a CRUD query, right? Can I access this query execution time/other info about it?

I want to monitor what does really make the software slower based on what it does execute on SQL Server (as I can't touch any code)

Comment: What are you actually asking here. Both the questions you are here are pretty vague.

Comment: i want to track/monitor execution time of all queries being executed on a SQL SERVER database.  i dont know how to export metrics for this on a SQL SERVER.

and want to use grafana to show it ( i'm used to grafana, could use any other solution)

Comment: It doesn't get into the query level, but SQLCAT wrote an article on how they monitor SQL on linux with grafana at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/how-the-sqlcat-customer-lab-is-monitoring-sql-on-linux. Start with that to get the metrics flowing into your dashboard and adapt as necessary.

Comment: *"i want to track/monitor execution time of all queries being executed on a SQL SERVER database."* That isn't a question. What are you actually asking? "I want" isn't a question, and "I don't know how" isn't either.

Comment: Larnu, ok lets make a question out of my text : "Is possible to track/monitor execution time of all queries being executed on a SQL SERVER database? And use Grafana to show that tracking ( show the metrics generated ) ? If yes, how?"